# Moving Project from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0: Suddenly Release Handle Failed

Tags: .net, frameworks

I just changed the targeted Framework of my project from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0 to benefit from the new features. But now when I start my program I get:

> A SafeHandle or CriticalHandle of type 'BitmapHandle' failed to
>   properly release the handle with value 0xB605123D. This usually
>   indicates that the handle was released incorrectly via another means
>   (such as extracting the handle using DangerousGetHandle and closing it
>   directly or building another SafeHandle around it.)

But I don't even know where to start looking for the cause of this I don't get any more information and on 3.5 everything was just fine.

Comment: I have that error as well after migrating to 4.0. You found a solution?

Comment: I found out that in my case it is related to having a splash screen. If I don't put a splash screen, the error goes away.

Comment: You're right, same thing for me. Very strange though... I removed the splash screen for now.

Comment: I decided to turn off Release Handle Failed exceptions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in the WPF SplashScreen class.  Still around in .NET 4.6  BitmapHandle is a SafeHandle class, its [ReleaseHandle()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Shared/MS/Win32/NativeMethodsOther.cs,35a3e2b593f6d035) method looks like this:

```
    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return UnsafeNativeMethods.DeleteObject(handle);
    }
```

Which is quite correct, it ensures that the GDI bitmap object is properly destroyed no matter what happens.  The bug is present in the [SplashScreen.DestroyResources()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/SplashScreen.cs,57538949b88b042f) method, it helps too much:

```
    private void DestroyResources()
    {
        //...
        if (_hBitmap != null && !_hBitmap.IsClosed)
        {
            UnsafeNativeMethods.DeleteObject(_hBitmap.MakeHandleRef(null).Handle);
            _hBitmap.Close();
            _hBitmap = null;
        }
        //...
    }
```

Two calls to `DeleteObject`, that's one too many.  The debugger has an MDA (Managed Debugging Assistant) that watches for bugs like this, it sees ReleaseHandle() failing and steps in.  You don't normally see this because (unwisely) that MDA is turned off by default.  Debug > Exceptions > Managed Debugging Assistants > ReleaseHandleFailed.  Untick it to stop getting the notification.

Bugs like this are pretty nasty, they open the door to handle recycle attacks.  The odds that it is actually exploitable are however very low, the Close() call immediately follows the DeleteObject() call and bitmaps are not particularly dangerous :)  Accidents are technically possible, you would have to have another thread creating GDI objects at the same time, that doesn't happen very often in a WPF app.

You can file the bug at connect.microsoft.com, a link to this Q+A ought to suffice.