# ReleaseHandleFailed was detected

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829308/moving-project-from-net-3-5-to-net-4-0-suddenly-release-handle-failed) happens in my WPF application as well.  I'm looking for more information as to why it happens when using a native .NET control; and how to prevent it if possible.  Is the only solution to ignore the exception?

Full exception message:

`ReleaseHandleFailed was detected
Message: A SafeHandle or CriticalHandle of type 'BitmapHandle' failed to properly release the handle with value 0x8305193A. This usually indicates that the handle was released incorrectly via another means (such as extracting the handle using DangerousGetHandle and closing it directly or building another SafeHandle around it.)`

Comment: That's a pretty strange handle value, the more likely scenario is that you are suffering from data corruption.  You haven't left a single clue how that could happen.  Isolate the problem, disable unmanaged code and use another machine.

Comment: @HansPassant The handle value changes every time I start my application.  I turned on all of my Execption options and the exception is thrown presumably after the splash screen is closed.  I set my .png file back to Build Action: Resource and the exception doesn't get thrown anymore.

Comment: Furthermore, turning on debugging unmanaged and using Break, my call stack location gives me `user32.dll!GetDC() + 0x6d bytes`. The exception is a part of Managed Debugging Assistant in Debug > Exceptions options.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/720719/releasehandlefailed-thrown-by-mda-when-using-the-splash-screen-feature-of-wpf